# AngularJS code of shopping cart remove items not working properly

Tags: angularjs

The corresponding `html` code is given below.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="myCart in cart">
           <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        <a href="#"><img src="{{myCart.src}}" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" alt="Product 2" /></a>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                       <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                           <li><a href="#">{{myCart.productName}}&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift"></span></a></li>
                           <li>{{myCart.manufacturer}}</li>
                           <li>{{myCart.specification}} | Qty {{myCart.quatntity}}</li>
                       </ul>
                       <ul style="list-style-type: none;margin-top:30px;">
                           <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>&nbsp;SAVE&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#" ng-click="removeItem(myCart.id)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>&nbsp;REMOVE</a></li>
                       </ul>
                   </div>
               </div>  
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
               {{myCart.delivery}}
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
               <i class="fa fa-inr"></i>&nbsp;{{myCart.toalAmount}}
           </div>
       </div>
```

The code of module is given below

```
var myModule = angular.module("myModule", []);  
myModule.controller("myController", ["$scope", function ($scope) 

{

$scope.cart = [{
    id: 1,
    src:"app/img/p"+1+".png",
    productName: "CAMERA",
    manufacturer: "Canon Black Camera",
    specification: "5 MeagaPixel",
    quatntity: 1,
    delivery: "12/03/2016",
    toalAmount:699
},

{
    id: 2,
    src: "app/img/p" + 2 + ".png",
    productName: "DINNER SET",
    manufacturer: "Lao Pala",
    specification: "full family set",
    quatntity: 1,
    delivery: "16/03/2016",
    toalAmount: 1799
},
{
    id: 3,
    src: "app/img/p"+3 +".png",
    productName: "LADIES BAG",
    manufacturer: "Crocodile Bag",
    specification: "5 mm leather",
    quatntity: 1,
    delivery: "29/03/2016",
    toalAmount: 899
}
];

$scope.removeItem = function (id) {
    $scope.cart.splice(id-1, 1);
}
}]);
```

The problem is stated below:

1) When I remove the item from bottom of cart item lists, the code is working fine but when I start removing items from the middle or top, then the last item which left doesn't get removed.
For removing I am using `splice()` method.

Please suggest me where I am missing.
Any documentation link will be also helpful for me.
Thanks in advance

Below is the screen shot.
[image: page screen shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope, [this Punker will help you](http://plnkr.co/edit/ne5aoC2EHl0Ncs1b3pqA?p=preview). You need to check using `$index`.

```
<li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>&nbsp;SAVE&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#" ng-click="removeItem($index)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>&nbsp;REMOVE</a></li>
```

Comment: Will fail however if any filters used since `$index` won't be reference to original data array. Generally safer to do your own indexing by passing in the object

Comment: @AliTauseefReza: Thanks Ali, charlietfl has a good point. You should consider that too. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this  :

In your HTML :

```
    <a href="#" ng-click="removeItem($index)">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
       &nbsp;REMOVE
   </a>
```

In controller :

```
$scope.removeItem = function (index) {
    $scope.cart.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use $index to specify the index of the element to remove, it's a built-in attribute of the ng-repeat directive

```
<a href="#" ng-click="removeItem($index)">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you remove item with id 2, your remove item cart[1] ( your "id-1"). So in your cart, you have cart with id 3 and 1. After if your want to remove cart with id 3, you want to remove cart[2], but you have only 2 cart left.
I think you must not use id but something like :

```
    ng-repeat="myCart in cart track by $index"
```

and use index in your "removeItem" function

Answer (score 0):

You should use the index of your array instead of the `id` of your data. The `id` of the data will not represent the order in which they appear in the array, especially if you intend to delete some items in the array.

You can use the [$index](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) instead :

```
<a href="#" ng-click="removeItem($index)">
```

Then :

```
$scope.removeItem = function (index) {
    $scope.cart.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
  Your array length is getting out of sync with the ID

detailed:
The problem is the that when you remove an element from the TOP your array is resized into a smaller one, but your objects inside doesn't change the IDs.

So you end up having an array with size 2, but your last element has id 3, the array is 0-based so to remove the last element you will need splice(1,1) and not splice(2,1).